# jquery: stop infinite recursion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I stop the infinite recursion here so that a mousedown event can be triggered just once? should it be in a separate method?

```
$(document).on('mouseover',function (e) {
            $(e.target).mousedown(function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                console.log('clicked');
                $(e.target).trigger('mousedown'); //use hello(e); instead?
                return;
            })
});

$(document).on('mousedown', 'a', function(e){
  hello(e);
});

function hello(e){
console.log('got it');
}
```

This seems to trigger a never ending loop. Basically I need to bind a mousedown handler on the currently  element under the mouse, which will fire a mousedown event that another handler will be able to handle.

The reason I am doing this is because the mouseover works on dynamically generated element so when this happens I need to bind a handler again as the `on` handler is not able to catch the newly generated element.

Comment: At the end of the `.mousedown()` handler, you are indirectly calling it again. That's where the recursion comes from. Why do you want to trigger it again after it has already been processed?

Comment: because it doesn't seem to fire `got it` in the other handler...should that be in a method of it's own so that it is called directly?

Comment: I think you don't need the whole `mouseover` handler at all as the `on` function will also consider dynamically added elements. Currently, you are stopping the event propagation which prevents the event from reaching the second handler printing "got it".

Comment: won't fire `hello()` if target isn't an `<a>`. You should elaborate on exactly what it is you want from all of this

Comment: You're adding a new mousedown event to every element you drag your mouse over. This is insane.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it complicated. Imagine everytime a user move his mouse an event will be added dynamically?

Why not design your element with class names and use it in your mousedown event? This way a sure call to mousedown will trigger always.

```
 $(".className").mousedown(function(e){
            console.log('clicked');
            return;
 })
```

--*The reason I am doing this is because the mouseover works on dynamically generated element so when this happens I need to bind a handler again as the on handler is not able to catch the newly generated element.*

If you say so then, add a className to your dynamically generated element to have your mousedown event bind to it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```js
 $(document).on('mouseover',function (e) {
                $(e.target).trigger('mousedown'); //use hello(e); instead?
                return;
    
});

 $(document).on('mousedown','a', function(e){
   hello(e);
 });

function hello(e){
alert('got it');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">hello</a>
```